# IIS 10.0 Orphaned requests listed in Worker Processes

Tags: windows, iis

Is there some way to end "orphaned" requests, I.E. requests in the app pool that nobody is waiting for anymore?

I have found that requests do not end when the user closes their browser.  The request remains until it finishes.  It is tying up bandwidth.

Advice is most appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is up to the web app developers to decide what to do when browsers abort, https://www.meziantou.net/handling-aborted-requests-in-asp-net-core.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close those requests. Directly select the application pool in the application pools for recycling. Or running IISRESET directly. You also can set [Recycling Settings for an Application Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/).